# How do I update Jenkins windowserver SVNkit

Tags: svn, jenkins

I need to update to get jenkins to use subversion 1.8.  I updated to the latest Jenkins Subversion plugin but I still see it still has svnkit-1.7.10-jenkins-1.jar.  Im assuming I have to install the latest SVNkit onto my jenkins server. but I don't see how to do it for windows system?  I downloaded the latest svn kit but don't see a Jenkin's jar file.   not clear on how to upgrade

Answer (score 1):

Did you update it through Jenkins / Manage Jenkins / Manage Plugins?

I've recently updated Subversion plugin to version 2.5 (which adds support for SVN 1.8) and all works fine.

In \plugins\subversion directory I see svnkit-1.8.6.jar (but you of course should never deal directly with this files).

Subversion plugin's page: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin.

Comment: yeah I did the update and Jenkins shows that an update is no longer required.